# Android API for opening camera and scanning QR code?

Tags: android, camera, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to develop an app that can open the camera and scan a given QR code. However, I have a constraint that states that I cannot use any 3rd party libraries like ZBar Code Reader or ZXingScanner as it would increase the size of my apk.

I was looking into Google's **Barcode APIs** given [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#3), but it didn't seem to perform what I want my app to perform, that is, it doesn't open any camera and do a live scanning on the image.

So, how can I make my app open the camera within specific bounds and perform a live scan on the QR code?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible. After all, you have to do this with zero bytes of code, as otherwise it will increase the size of your APK.

Comment: @Auro: There's more to the Barcode API documentation than that link you shared (e.g. [advanced example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision))... And of course you can do the barcode reading live through the camera with the Google Api.

Check https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/ for an simplified version demonstrating the barcode (qr-code) scanning using the Google API.

Answer (score 0):

Google barcode api provide support to opening camera. here is sample code

> ```
>     // A barcode detector is created to track barcodes.  An associated multi-processor instance
>     // is set to receive the barcode detection results, track the barcodes, and maintain
>     // graphics for each barcode on screen.  The factory is used by the multi-processor to
>     // create a separate tracker instance for each barcode.
>     BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
>     BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(mGraphicOverlay);
>     barcodeDetector.setProcessor(
>             new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());
>
>     if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational()) {
>         // Note: The first time that an app using the barcode or face API is installed on a
>         // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
>         // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
>         // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any barcodes
>         // and/or faces.
>         //
>         // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native libraries are currently
>         // available.  The detectors will automatically become operational once the library
>         // downloads complete on device.
>         Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies are not yet available.");
>
>         // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
>         // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
>         IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
>         boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;
>
>         if (hasLowStorage) {
>             Toast.makeText(this, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Creates and starts the camera.  Note that this uses a higher resolution in comparison
>     // to other detection examples to enable the barcode detector to detect small barcodes
>     // at long distances.
>     CameraSource.Builder builder = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), barcodeDetector)
>             .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
>             .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
>             .setRequestedFps(15.0f);
>
>     // make sure that auto focus is an available option
>     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
>         builder = builder.setFocusMode(
>                 autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null);
>     }
>
>     mCameraSource = builder
>             .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
>             .build();
> }
> ```

you can refere to google barcode sample here

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader

Comment: Is there any step by step tutorial on how they created the CameraSource, or just how to scan immediately when qr code is detected (without triggering capture)